# How to guard execution when 'USE' not supported in SQL

Tags: t-sql, ssms

When I'm sketching out SQL statements I have a file of all the queries I have used to analyse my live data. Each time I write a new statement or group of statements at the end of the fileI select them and click 'execute' to see the results. I'm paranoid that I may forget the selection stage and accidentally run all the queries sequentially in the entire file and so I head the file with the line

```sql
USE FakeDatabase
```

so that the queries will fail as they will be run against a non-existing database. But no, instead I get the error

> USE statement is not supported to switch between databases

(N.B. I am using SQL Server Management Studio v17.0 RC1 against a v12 Azure SQL Server database.)

What tSQL statement can I use that will prevent further execution of tSQL statements in a file?

Comment: You could comment out your queries: (Ctrl+A, Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C) and only uncomment it (Ctrl+A, Ctrl+K, Ctrl+U) immediately before execution.

Comment: I do that for the really destructive ones (double paranoia!) but it makes the historic queries harder to scan through as you don't get the syntax highlighting for comments

Comment: I'm using the wrong nomenclature then - perhaps I mean "statement". Things like `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `TRUNCATE`, `DELETE`, ... are the ones I make sure are commented out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use is not supported in AZURE...you can try below ,but there can be many options depending on your use case

Replace use Database with below statement

```
 if db_name() <>'Fakedatabase'
 return;
```

Comment: Looking again at this I may be able to use `RETURN` on its own since that will prevent any following statements being executed.

Answer (score 1):

You could, instead, put something like this in each script:

```
IF @@SERVERNAME <> 'Not-Really-My-Server'
BEGIN
    raiserror('Database Name Not Set', 20, -1) with log
END

-- Rest of my query...
```

Comment: I'm getting errors like `Only System Administrator can specify WITH LOG option for RAISERROR command` and then `Error severity levels greater than 18 can only be specified by members of the sysadmin role` which I will need to investigate. After those errors the rest of my query runs :-(

Comment: Sadly not. Setting the level to '1' and removing the `WITH LOG` I get the message "Database Name Not Set, Msg 5000, Level 1, State 1" followed by the message `(1167 row(s) affected)` and the results of the `SELECT`

Comment: @dumbledad I think you need 18 to exit? maybe? /shrug

Comment: That one gives an odd response. I do not get the results of the `SELECT` but I do get its message '(1167 row(s) affected)' followed by 'Msg 50000, Level 18, State 1, Line 26' then 'Database Name Not Set'. So swapping to '18' has reversed the order of execution but suppressed displaying the 'SELECT' results. Very odd. I'll +1 though, just-in-case others who find this are administrators on their DB